# WordPress CSS doesn't update

Tags: css, ftp

I've got a new WordPress website that I'm testing that hasn't been updating properly when CSS styles are updated over FTP. I haven't got a cache plugin and I have cleared my browser cache and have tried a different browser. The changes I make are definitely being uploaded to style.css as I have downloaded it and checked it on a web FTP site. I can tell the code is not wrong because I have copied it to a new file, included it in header.php and it has changed. Also, when I delete style.css, the styles on the page do not change.

I've checked my HTML a hundred times and I'm not including other stylesheets and making huge obvious changes to styles doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Template has 2 style sheets, one that is unused.

By default WordPress will look for style.css in the editor but this doesn't necessary mean its used in the header.php

Take a look at your source code and view which css files are being loaded.

I suspect your see it something like: `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/css/blah.css`

Rather than `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css`

Comment: Yep! I should have known this, it's happened many times when I've converted static pages to WordPress.

Comment: I've just updated a few things and its doing the same thing in the theme directory root.